# href="#" Going to Top of Page - Prevent?

Tags: anchor, href, hashtag

I have a page with some jQuery functions. The HTML on the page looks like so:

```
<a href="#" class="service">Open</a>
```

When I click the Open button a hidden panel slides out. The jQuery itself works great however when I click the button it also takes me to the top of the page.

Is this the defualt behavior and how do I prevent every `href="#"` from taking me to the top of the page.

Note: I could add id's and tell the href to direct to that ID. I do not want to do that for various reasons (including adding unnecessary code).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In your event handler, add `e.preventDefault();` (assuming `e` is the name of the variable holding the event):

```js
$('.service').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You may also need to use `return false` at the end of your code block to ignore the browser default of scrolling to the top of the page.

Comment: @bafromca: Absolutely not. Calling `preventDefault` is sufficient; as its name implies, it prevents the default action (following the anchor and going to the top of the page) from occurring. `return false` does this too, and also does the equivalent of calling `stopPropagation` which, as the name suggests, stops the event from propagating up to parent elements; but if all you want to do is prevent the browser from scrolling to the top of the page, there is *no need* for `return false`.

Comment: Another solution for links that don't have a class like the OP - `$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 126):

```
<a href="#!" class="service">Open</a>
```

Comment: This works fine. But can you add some explanation as to why this works?

Comment: I think this is an anchor syntax. Scroll to element with id="!" but element with id="!" does not exist in document and browser does not scroll. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1

Comment: WoW! Best Solution! Thanks a lot. I wish I could upvote it 10 times!

Comment: By far the simplest solution - works without JQuery unlike the rest

Comment: I didn't knew that it would work like a charm and the great part is i do not have to add jquery extra code for it too.

Comment: THANKS a lot!! didn't know this exists

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Wish everything could be as simple as this.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108, any idea why?

Comment: Hacking HTML since 1996. And still nuts and bolts to learn. Thanks

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer?

Comment: Results in issues using Code Sniffer (WCAG2AA Standard): No Item found with Id "!"

Comment: What are you?!!

Comment: by far this hack is better than any JS solution,

Comment: Best Answer by far.  Simple and elegant with no JS overhead

Comment: You are the man! Best answer I've seen here. Haha

Comment: And after 20 years of HTML development ...

Answer (score 26):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="service">Open</a>
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
   var a = $(".service");
   a.click(function()
   {

       return false;

   });
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
   var a = $(".service");
   a.click(function(e)
   {

       e.preventDefault();

   });
});
```

**OR**

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" class="service">Open</a>
```

Comment: the 4th solution helped me as I don't have access to the js script, thanks

Comment: I also liked the inline solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('service').click(function() {
<your code>
return false;
});
```

`return false` overrides the standard behavior of the ‘a’ tag and stops the browser returning to the top of the page when clicked.